# store exception ex as string in db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public static bool download()
{
    try
    {
        //perform up dates, if successful
        UpdateActionResultTable("DownloadPOS", "N/A - No Sales file to upload", "Success", "N/A");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exeption ex)
    {
        UpdateActionResultTable("DownloadPOS", "N/A - No Sales file to upload", "Fail", ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

If unsuccessful I want to store the exception as a string in the db. This is from the UpdateActionResultTable function but it throws error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Any idea as to why?

works fine when the update is successful so my only guess is because of the exception?

```
public static void UpdateActionResultTable(string actionCalled, string salesFile, string result, string reason)
{
    EPOSEntities db = new EPOSEntities();

    ActionResult action = new ActionResult()
    {
         Action = actionCalled,
         File = salesFile,
         TimeStamp =  DateTime.Now,
         Result = result,
         Reason = reason                  
    };

    db.AddToActionResults(action);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that your final parameter is too long:

```
ex.ToString()
```

It cannot be written to the database, because the column you are writing to has a lower size limit.

So, either make that string you write shorter (filter out unnecessary data or take only the first *n* characters) or make the field you are writing that string to in the DB bigger.

Answer (score 1):

The column you have in your database where you are storing the string value for the exception is **not large enough to hold the exception string** you are giving it.

I would change that column in the database to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. To do that just run the SQL script below on your database if you are using SQL Server.

SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your database field is not big enough to store the exception string

N/A takes only 3 characters, but exceptions can get quite big. So if your field is lets say varchar(50), "N/A" would be no problem because the field can hold up to 50 characters. But an exception stored as string will be way bigger